# Content Missing - Javascript with CDATA

Tags: javascript, cdata

I am working with a client that runs a subscription website that plays embedded videos via javascript.  Suddenly SOME of the videos stopped loading for the members.

I know, next to nothing about Javascript with CDATA but I noticed that the code on the page with the broken videos is as follows:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
var playerhost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ezs386ed65eac750a03981460786bfd83bd9.s3.amazonaws.com/Screencasts/ezs3js/secure/" : "http://ezs386ed65eac750a03981460786bfd83bd9.s3.amazonaws.com/Screencasts/ezs3js/player/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + playerhost + "flv/7A8982DC-E9D7-D32B-4E1D561336E838BB.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
// ]]></script>
```

On a page where the videos are loading correctly there is a different Javascript embed code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerhost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ezs386ed65eac750a03981460786bfd83bd9.s3.amazonaws.com/Screencasts/ezs3js/secure/" : "http://ezs386ed65eac750a03981460786bfd83bd9.s3.amazonaws.com/Screencasts/ezs3js/player/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + playerhost + "flv/7A899626-C7B6-2D94-AD06D645F57C90A6.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

Both of these were working up until a week ago and can't account for why the CDATA code is no longer working.

Can anyone explain this based on what you see here?

Comment: cdata is for xml. those lines are irrelevant to JS, since they're commented-out (`//`).

Comment: "Suddenly stopping to work" usually means, that something else is involved. Was there a browser update in the corporate intranet?  A change in the web server? CloudFlare or another CDN put in front? Any change in the delivery between the HTML on disk and the visitor?

Comment: and the differences between the two are **NOT** "javascript". they're text-in-strings, which means nothing to JS. e.g. your urls are incorrect/outdated.

Comment: When I go back to the ezs3 CDN it appears that the embed code has now changed for all videos and they removed the CDATA reference. So perhaps they are no longer supporting those embed codes?

Comment: I also don't understand why the enclosed the entire script in the CDATA tags.  My understanding is that this is meant to prevent XML parsing of text

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a change by the CDN network that was causing the issue.